# Can I include a correlated dummy in a Fixed Effects Model?

Tags: r, categorical-data, fixed-effects-model

I am researching whether an increased number of women in a board of directors has influence on the company's performance.

I have conducted a hausman test and am using a fixed effects model.

My model includes several uncorrelated independent variables / controls like R&D-Budget, Board size, usw.

I have a diversity index to measure the amount of women in percent, the values range from 0-100, and I have a dummy that just stands for the absolute value of 3 or more women per board. (0= less then three / 1= three or more)

Can I bring both these values in one regression, or would they skew my results? (Which I suspect they do)

Answer (score 0):

If the variables measure the same "thing"/phenomenon, your model could suffer from multicolinearity, which would inflate your standard errors (e.g. the precision of your statistical model).

Suppose you start running a model without the dummy, and obtain a precisely estimated (low standar errors) effect. Now, if you run the model with both variables included and see that coefficients on both have a low precision (i.e. high standard errors), you should investigate if they are highly correlated (i.e. measure the same phenomenon). Standard errors are proportional to the correlation between any two sets of variables (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor).

If they are highly correlated, it possibly indicates that your model cannot differentiate between the effects (if there indeed are two seperate ones) as they measure the same thing. It could also be the case that they do not have any bearing on your dependent variable, but then you would expect that the single variable regression (+ controls) turned out the have an insignificant coefficent.

What your model's effectively saying is (as I interpret your model) that there is some threshold at three women in which there is an extra effect, and at the same time there is some effect from adding more women to the board. You might also consider if this logic, and the results you obtain, are consistent.

Comment: You got my model exactly right, I want to find out whether more women equal more performance and if at 3+ women, this performance behaves differently (positive/negative or stronger/weaker).

So from what I read from your comment, I can run my model with both variables included? 

Or should I first run both seperately, then joined and see if the standard errors change?

Comment: If so, I would suggest you use an interaction variable between 3+-dummy and female proportion, like: beta_2*D(>=3)*prop + *beta_1*prop. As of now, you test if there is a single "bump" when there are more than three women, and not a shift in the effect of proportion (correct?). Moreover, I suggest you start with the most parsimonious model. In your case, this might be there are no extra effect at 3+, corresponding to running a model with only proportions, and testing this against a model with 3+-interaction. Be advised that I am unfamiliar with your research's specific, so consider carefully!

Comment: Yes, that totally makes sense. I didn't even know this possibility existed, thank you!

This page also explained it seemingly well:

https://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2014/04/08/interpreting-interaction-coefficient-in-r-part1-lm/

Edit: Just read your edit. Yes, your assumption is correct. I want to see whether a higher female share increases performance, but expect a expecially high effect at 3+. 

In case I run two sparse models, one with only the dummy and one with only the proportion, depending on my significance and regression I can decide whther it's worth joing them, correct?

Comment: I think I got it wrong the first time, once with only the proportions and once with the proportions AND 3+, correct?

Comment: Yes, with an interaction between 3+ and proportion, please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics), where x1=prop, and x2 = 3+. The first model under "Introdction" section is what you proposed (I think) and latter is what I suggested. This differs, as in intepret it, from your first suggestion in the quesiton.